# How to add a User to DevCentre to Manage or View the Account

Tags: windows-dev-center

Is there a way to add a user to my DevCentre account so that they can view the reports, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Microsoft support and got the following response:

> Unfortunately, this is not an offered functionality at this time.

The same response referred me to [Windows Dev Platform UserVioce site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform) and I found the following request https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/3820213-allow-multiple-microsoft-accounts-to-manage-a-dev marked as "WORKING ON IT".

In short, it is not supported now, but it will come one day.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to manage multiple users in Dev Center is now available. There are additional details, including the description of the different roles on the link below:

[MSDN Manage Account Users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt489008.aspx)

The blog entry related to the release is below:

[December Dev Center update: Multi-user and other new capabilities](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/12/10/december-dev-center-update-multi-user-and-other-new-capabilities/)